# What is my misunderstanding in this question?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

This is a question from Dummit/Foote, Chapter 10.3 question 5. I am 100% sure I am misunderstanding this question. Do not write me a solution, I am not asking that.

> Let $R$ be a integral domain. Prove every finitely generated torsion module has a nonzero annihilator i.e. there exists nonzero $r\in R $ such that $rm = 0$

The definition of torsion here $M = Tor(M) = \{m : \exists r\neq 0, rm = 0 \} = RA$

Annihilator $Ann(M) = \{ \mu \in R: \mu m = 0,\forall m \in M \} $.

Since $M$ is torsion, every element will have a nonzero $r$ such the $rm = 0$, so $Ann(M) \neq 0$. What am I misunderstanding? What are these additional assumptions for?

Comment: Torsion means that for each element, there is some nonzero $r\in R$ that annihilates it. Here they are asking you to prove that that there is a nonzero $r\in R$ that annihilates *every* element of $m$, same scalar for every element. The elements of the annihilator must annihilate *every* element, not just some of them.

Comment: you are missing that for  $\mu$ to be in the annihilator, you haveto have that  that $\mu \cdot m =0$ FOR ALL $m \in M$.

Comment: Basically a "uniform" $r\neq 0$ that annihilates $M$?

Comment: Basically a *single* $r\neq 0$ that annihilates $M$. The elements of $\mathrm{Ann}(M)$ are the ones that annihilate the entire module, not just some elements of it.